# Javascript/PHP: Script to set selected <SELECT> option not working

Tags: php, javascript, html, web

I have a select statement running which pulls data into $row.

```
$result = mysql_query("Select * FROM Recipes WHERE rID = $sent_rID");   
$fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result);
$error = mysql_error($link);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Next I have my SELECT block

```
<select name='department' id='department'>
<option value='Deli'>Deli</option>
<option value='Meat'>Meat</option>
<option value='Seafood'>Seafood</option>
</select>
```

Finally I have the following SCRIPT block

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='javascript'>
DepartmentSelect($row[rDepartment]);
</SCRIPT>
```

And here is DepartmentSelect()

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function DepartmentSelect(itemToSelect)
{
// Get a reference to the drop-down
var myDropdownList = document.inputForm.department;

// Loop through all the items
for (iLoop = 0; iLoop< myDropdownList.options.length; iLoop++)
{    
    if (myDropdownList.options[iLoop].value == itemToSelect)
     {
       // Item is found. Set its selected property, and exit the loop
       myDropdownList.options[iLoop].selected = true;
       break;
     }
 }
}
</script>
```

I have verified multiple times that all of the values are good, but for some reason the combobox refuses to show the right value. Any ideas?

**Edit:** The SCRIPT block occurs within a php echo, so it is pulling the correct value.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Thanks for the information! I'll certainly look into it and update as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add quotes.

Your code would output:

```
DepartmentSelect(Deli)
```

Rather do this:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='javascript'>
DepartmentSelect('<?=$row["rDepartment"];?>');
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Worked! Everything was in an echo block already, but throwing apostrophe's around $row[rDepartment] made all the difference.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='javascript'>
DepartmentSelect(<?php echo $row[rDepartment]; ?>);
</SCRIPT>
```

or:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='javascript'>
DepartmentSelect(<?php echo $row["rDepartment"]; ?>);
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Ah sorry, I should have added that this the script block occurs within a php echo, so it is pulling the correct value.